# Puppeteer: proper selection of inner text

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to grab a string that has a particular class name, lets say 'CL1'.

This is what is used to do and it worked:
(we are inside an asycn function)

```
var counter = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelector('.CL1').innerText;
        });
```

Now, after some months, when i try to run the code i get this error:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

I did some debugging with some `console.log()` before and after the previous snippet of code and found out that this is the culprit.

I looked the code of the webpage and the particular class is inside.

But i found out two more classes with the same name.

All three of them are nested deep inside many classes.

So what is the proper way to selected the one i want, given i know the class hierarchy for the one i am interested in?

EDIT:
Since there are three class names with the same name, and i want to extract info from the first, can i use an array notation on the querySelector() to access the information from the first one?

EDIT2:
I run this:

```
return document.querySelector('.CL1').length;
```

and i got

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

This gets even more confusing...

EDIT 3:
I trie the suggestion of Md Abu Taher and i saw that the snippet of code he provided did not return undefined. This means that the selector is visible to my code.

Then i run this snippet of code:

```
var counter = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelector('#react-root > section > main > div > header > section > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a > span').innerText;
            });
```

And i got back the same error:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

Comment: can you provide us with the url of the page you're trying to access?

Comment: Other than making sure that the class name didn't change, verify that you're waiting for the page to load before calling `querySelector`.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Thank you for the effort, but it is an intranet URL

Comment: @zaquest Yes, this is handled just fine.

Comment: are you waiting for the content to be loaded in the dom?

Comment: You can pass { headless: false } to the puppeteer.launch method. This helps in debugging.

Comment: @JoeyGough Thanks but i am waiting for everything to load already.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is divided in to parts. Getting right selector, and getting data.

## 1. Getting right Selector

### Use inspect element

- Right click on your desired element and click inspect element.
- Then right click and click Copy > Copy selector
  [image]

This will give you a unique selector for that specific element.

### Use a selector tool

There are bunch of chrome extension that helps you find the right selector.

- [Selectorgadget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=en)
- [Get Unique CSS Selector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-unique-css-selector/lkfaghhbdebclkklgjhhonadomejckai?hl=en)
- [Copy Css Selector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-css-selector/kemkenbgbgodoglfkkejbdcpojnodnkg?hl=en)

## 2. Getting the data

Given your selector is **.CL1**, you need to do few things.

### Wait for all Network events to finish

Basically on a navigation you can wait until network is idle.

```
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
```

### Wait for the element to appear in DOM.

Even if the network is idle, there might be redirect etc. Best choice is to wait until the element appears. The following will wait until the element is found and will throw an error otherwise.

```
await page.waitFor('.CL1');
```

### Or, Check if element exists and return data only if it exists

If you do not want to throw an error or if the element appears randomly, you need to check it's existence and return data.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const element = document.querySelector('.CL1');
  return element && element.innerText; // will return undefined if the element is not found
});
```

Comment: Read my answer completely and apply what I wrote there. :) You used domcontentloaded instead of networkidle2 or networkidle0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195402/discussion-between-md-abu-taher-and-user1584421).

Answer (score 1):

try to verify the element before

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
```

OR

```
var x = document.getElementsById("example");
```

and then

```
var counter = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return x.innerText;
        });
```

Comment: I did this: var counter = await page.evaluate(() => {
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("CL1");
   console.log(x);
   return x.innerText;
  });
 console.log(counter);

Comment: And i got this { undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined}

Comment: try to use innerHTML instead of innerText // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML

Comment: this link might helps [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Examples)